# Visual Studio RegEx Replace - 2 or more?

Tags: visual-studio, regex

Using visual studio search and replace, is there a way to search for two or more instances of something?  Visual Studio regex does not seem to support the "{}" syntax for indicating quantity.

E.G:

```
Match Text: 11 OR 111 OR 1111
Standard Regex: [1]{2,}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do "two or more" you have to repeat yourself to match one and then one-or more.

```
11+
```

or

```
[1][1]+
```

(the latter is only useful if you want more than one digit to match, e.g., `[123][123]+`.)

Answer (score 0):

The you could try:

```
11+
// or
111*
```

Which would result in the same (matches 2 or more '1'-s).